# R: Stanford CoreNLP returnning NAs for getSentiment

Tags: r, stanford-nlp, stanford-nlp-server, corenlp-server

I have the following text data:

> I always prefer old-school guy. I have a PhD degree in science. I am
>   really not interested in finding someone with the same background,
>   otherwise life is gonna be boring.

And I am trying to extract out the sentiment scores of the above text, but what i get is all NAs.

```
 dating3 = annotateString(bio)
 bio.emo = getSentiment(dating3)

   id sentimentValue sentiment
1   1             NA        NA
2   2             NA        NA
3   3             NA        NA
```

I do not know why is occuring and googled around but did not find any relevant answers. In the meantime, when i tried the sample data provided within coreNLP package

```
 getSentiment(annoHp)

   id sentimentValue    sentiment
1  1              4 Verypositive
```

It gives me an answer, so I don't know why this is happening. Would greatly appreciate if anyone can offer some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully by now you have already found this but for you and anyone else, this is a known bug which is fixed on the GitHub version, see here: https://github.com/statsmaths/coreNLP/issues/9